# How do I change the height of the HeaderCell in React-Data-Grid?

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rdg-cell-editing-r1sqz) is a basic grid in CodeSandbox. When I define my `columns` object, for one of the columns I pass in the property `headerRenderer` as a simple React Component showing some text and a red background. I made the height 100 on this component so it would expand the header cell. That did not work.

I went into Chrome dev tools and tried changing a bunch of css properties on various parent elements, but to no avail: the displayed height of the header is always 35px.

Notice in the link I also defined `override.css` which is specifically defining the height of the `.react-grid-HeaderCell` class.

What am I missing that the height of this Header won't budge?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prop name `headerRowHeight` can bed used to set height for the header cell. 
In your example, it will be as

```
<ReactDataGrid
          columns={columns}
          rowGetter={i => this.state.rows[i]}
          rowsCount={3}
          onGridRowsUpdated={this.onGridRowsUpdated}
          enableCellSelect={true}
          headerRowHeight={50}
        />
```